# Nodejs turn 2 middlewares into 1

Tags: javascript, node.js

Hi everyone so I have a post method in `expressJS` with middlewares and I want to shorten them here is the original post method:

```
router.post('/', Validate.Schemas('CreateUser'), Validate.validate, (req, res) => {

});
```

and I want to change it into this:

```
router.post('/', Validate.Schemas('CreateUser').validate, (req, res) => {

});
```

And here is the `Validate` file:

```
const { body, validationResult } = require('express-validator/check');

exports.validate = (req, res) => {
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
        return res.status(422).json({ errors: errors.array() })
    }
};

exports.Schemas = (schema) => {
    switch (schema) {

        //Create New User Schema
        case 'CreateUser': {
            return [
                body('username', 'Invalid input.').exists().isString(),
                body('password', 'Invalid input.').exists().isString(),
                body('email', 'Invalid input.').exists().isEmail(),
                body('DOB', 'Invalid input.').exists(),
                body('products').optional().isArray(),
                body('isStaff').optional().isBoolean(),
            ]
        }


    }
};
```

Any help is appreciated thanks.

Comment: Do you have other schemas? It seems like your switch statement is unnecessary.

Comment: @IronFlare I'm planning to add more

Comment: something like:  `app.route("/api/:api_version/your/route").post(func1, func2);` and call `next()` at end of func1?  and middleware functions can be like this:  `const func1 = async (req, res, next) => {  } );`

Comment: From looking at the documentation for [express-validator](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/), it seems like the way you're using it now is the intended usage. Is there a reason you need to subvert the developer-intended methods other than saving 10 characters?

Comment: @IronFlare currently there is no particular reason, I just tried doing it to enhance my skills but couldn't find a way to do it, so I asked maybe someone knew.